# Image upload to AWS s3 :Allow only jpg and png images

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, laravel-5

I am trying to upload only certain type of images into aws s3 bucket.
For that i've added the following rule to my bucket policy

```
"Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>/*.jpg",
                "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket name>/*.png",
            ]
```

This works fine ,however when i change extension of text file to png
(eg: change `sample.txt` to `sample.png`) and try to upload its uploaded.

How can i prevent this??.

One solution i've founded is add a php image validation in my code and upload to AWS s3 ,but here i am using [s3 direct browser upload](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html)   in this method  there is no need of normal way of php file upload  also reduces the server overload.
So i think adding php image validation on s3 direct browser upload is bad practise.

Comment: This is impossible to do without opening the file and checking what's in it (which S3 won't do as part of its policy).

Comment: So how can i solve this use php image validation??

Comment: Yes, use PHP image validation. Basically if you get a png do a `imagecreatefrompng` and check if it succeeds and if you get a jpg do a `imagecreatefromjpeg` (requires [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php))